# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm trying to get the price from a item in a combobox.Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Aplicatie_proiect
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form

    {
        private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connection.ConnectionString =    @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\SleepyHitman-      V2\Documents\Inventory1.accdb;
    Persist Security Info=False;";
        }

        private void txt_order_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Double PT = new Double();
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "insert into Comenzi (Produs,Cantitate) values('"+txt_Produs.Text+"','"+txt_Cantitate.Text+"',)" ; //+ sa adaug useru care e logat din form 1
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = "select * from Inventory";
            command.CommandText = query;
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                txt_Produs.Items.Add(reader["Produs"].ToString());
            }
            connection.Close();

        }
        private void txt_Produs_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            **connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = "select * from Inventory where Pret ='" + txt_Produs.Text + "'";
            command.CommandText = query;
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                txt_Pret.Text = reader["Pret"].ToString();

            }
            connection.Close();**
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: You should more clearly state what and where the problem is, as well as what you expect.

Comment: i want to get the Price(Pret) when i select an item from the combo box, so the user can see what the price of the item is and after that select the quantity.

Comment: Please edit your question and don't post code in the comments. It's unreadable there.

Comment: from txt_Produs_selectedIndexChanged there is my problem
Also srry for the bad description i didnt sleep last night and is hard to concentrate right now + i have an exam in 20 minutes and i try to repeat for it too

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where you get the error. Next time try to be more explicit.

In the abobe code I see that you use string concatenation for building the sql statements. That is a bad practice due a sql injection and type missmatching.

Try to change

```
private void txt_order_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Double PT = new Double();
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "insert into Comenzi (Produs,Cantitate) values('"+txt_Produs.Text+"','"+txt_Cantitate.Text+"',)" ; //+ sa adaug useru care e logat din form 1
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

by this (I suspect the error is in the conversion of Cantitate -in a textBox- to a int or double -in database-):

```
private void txt_order_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Double PT = new Double();
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "insert into Comenzi (Produs,Cantitate) values(@product, @cantitate)" ; //+ sa adaug useru care e logat din form 1
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product", txt_Produs.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cantitate", Convert.ToInt32(txt_Cantitate.Text);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: ty for pointing that out i tried to change something there and forgot to undo unfortunately that wasn't the problem i still get the error here '
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();'

Comment: In the line `string query = "select * from Inventory where Pret ='" + txt_Produs.Text + "'";` What data type is the field **Pret**?

Comment: it was string cause i did want to leave it simple ussualy Pret(price) its a int but i parsed it later, after alot of hours i found the problem string query = "select Pret from Inventory where Produs ='" + txt_Produs.Text + "'";

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are comparing a numerical field here. In that case you need to remove the single quotes in the sql query string.

Answer (score 0):

```
string query = "select Pret from Inventory where Produs ='" + txt_Produs.Text + "'";
```

this was the problem, ty for the help guys hope i will be more clear next time.